# How to get value of a td and cut a part of it?

Tags: jquery, html, string, html-table

I have a table like that:

```
<tr style="color: green;" id="bankRecord377">      
  <td align="center"> <input type="checkbox" value="377" name="377"></td>     
  <td align="center" id="started">19.25 USD</td>
  <td align="center">392</td>
</tr>
```

How can I get 19.25 TL and then get 19.25 from there? (I can add id for that td too)

**EDIT:** I made a mistake while asking question and edited it.

Comment: If the cell contains "19.1 USD", do you want to get 19 or 19.1?

Comment: You have  a "name" attribute on a `<td>`, you'll want to change that to class/id.

Comment: @Sjoerd I just edited it before your comment. I want 19.1 Voting up both for your comment and answer.

Comment: @Dunhamzzz you are right. I change it to id.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, you want the currency part (the center TD) from the row, right?

If you can give the TD with the name "started" an ID of "started", an easy solution using jQuery might be:

```
var currency1 = $("td#started").html(); // gets 19.25 USD
var currency2 = parseFloat(currency1.split(" ")[0]); // gets 19.25
```

Comment: I'm voting up, thanks but I editted my question to be more clear.

Comment: Thanks for the vote - you can just replace "parseInt" with "parseFloat" in that case...

Answer (score 2):

```
var tdContent = $('#bankRecord377 td[name=started]').html();
// or var tdContent = $('#idOfTd').html();
var number = +tdContent.replace(/[^0-9.]/g, '');
```

Answer (score 0):

var currency = parseInt($('td[name=started]', '#bankRecord377').text().replace('USD', ''));

Comment: parseInt ignores any non-numeric content, so you don't have to replace 'USD' before passing it to parseInt. `parseInt(td.text())` would also return 19.

Answer (score 0):

```
var td = document.getElementById('bankRecord377').getElementsByTagName('td')[1];
var value = td.innerHTML.split(" ")[0]; // 19.0
var value2 = parseInt(value); // 19
```